# 413 (Payload Too Large) error in SharedMap

Tags: fluid-framework

When I convert an xml document to fluid DDS using SharedMap and SharedObjectSequence and set it in the fluid container I get the error 413 (Payload Too Large). Error response:

```
{"message":"request entity too large","expected":109452,"length":109452,"limit":102400,"type":"entity.too.large"}
```

I am trying this in https://github.com/microsoft/FluidHelloWorld. I am using tinylicious and localhost. It works fine for small xml files. I did a quick search through the code and didn't find where this is enforced.

Is it possible to increase this limit?

Comment: Elango, it sounds like you're using a SharedMap and a SharedObjectSequence, but how much data are you putting into each SharedMap key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running up against a max request size in the web server rather than a Fluid Framework issue.

If you want to enable Tinylicious to handle larger request sizes, you would clone the Fluid Framework repository and modify the configuration of the Express service.

So go to [tinylicious/src/app.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/main/server/tinylicious/src/app.ts) and add `app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));` This will raise the request limit. To use your modified Tinylicious, you'd compile and run the service locally.

Alternatively, you can break up the XML and set parts of the XML into the keys of the DDSs.

Without knowing your scenario, I'd lean towards the solution of breaking up the XML because it'll lead to lower latency updates. For instance, as you read in the XML, set the tag pairs in the Shared Object Sequence immediately, then keep reading and continue for the children objects.

---

You may want to open an issue on the repo because the max request body size should cause a clearer error. The service should also accept up to the max Kafka message size, which is the true limiting factor.

Comment: Adding this line in tinylicious/src/app.ts fixed the issue: 
`app.use(bodyParser.raw({ limit: requestSize }));`
I did try setting the object in the parent before reading further down the xml tree, but I still had the same 413 error.